# How to let admin to force user redirect logout page on client after expired session user on server? Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

How to let admin to force user redirect logout page on client after expired session user on server? Spring security
On server:

```
public void expireUserSessions(String username) {
        for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
            if (principal instanceof org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) {
                UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) principal;
                if (userDetail.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                    for (SessionInformation information : sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(userDetail, true)) {
                        information.expireNow();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After click a link on client redirect logout page success.
But I want when expire session on server, auto redirect logout page on client!

Comment: There is no such trigger inbuild from Server side. If you want to do it you can add a timer in UI which calls some API, if session is expired server will redirect to errro page automatically.

Comment: @MyTwoCents my boss want to it straightway logout. :(((